# Listview и поиск android

Tags: android

Добрый вечер. Имеется ListView, при нажатии на пункт из которого, считывается позиция элемента и открывается новое активити. Пример:

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

        //Позиция элемента, по которому кликнули
        String itemname = new Integer(position).toString);

        //Создаем новый intent
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(FirstActivity.this, ViewActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("defStrID", itemname); //defStrID - уникальная строка, отправим itemname в другое Activity
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent); //запускаем intent
            }
    });
```

Работает такой вариант отлично. Проблема при добавлении поиска в ListView. Делаю как здесь: [тыц](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/)

Допустим есть список:

```
0000
1111
2222
3333
```

Если в поиск забить 3, то останется одна строка "3333" в ListView - все отлично, так и должно быть. Затем, при нажатии на эту ссылку отправляется позиция элемента в следующее активити, где и происходит ошибка, открывается не тот элемент, который нужен (нужен 4, т.к. 3333 находится в 4 строке). Пробовал вместо

```
String itemname = new Integer(position).toString);
```

использовать

```
String itemname = new Long(id).toString);
```

но `id` и `position` совпадают, после поиска. Как быть в такой ситуации? Нужно, чтобы при вводе текста в строку поиска, отфильтровался `ListView` и при нажатии на элемент передавался его настоящая позиция, которая была до фильтрования.

Comment: тут нет самого главного - как у вас поиск организован

Answer (score 1):

все правильно тут работает

1. `String itemname = new Integer(position).toString);`   - это ужасное шаманство, не делай так, так как `position` - это позиция в списке, если элемент 1 - она всегда будет 0, (это и происходит у тебя в коде)
2. Это можно поправить использую для твоих целей, например, `v.getText();`
3. Возможно лучше написать свой апаптер, передавать в него объекты со своим `UID`